# Configure Field analysis handler - Solr 4

Tags: solr, lucene, analysis

I am working on a test Solr instance using Solr4 (beta) - I am able to see the schema, query data. It works fine!

When I click on the analysis tab in Solr Admin, I get the analysis form.
However, when I submit the form, I get an error message - 
"This Functionality requires the /analysis/field Handler to be registered and active!"

This is the ajax call that is actually performed and it returns a 404.

> http:// localhost:8989/solr/core1/analysis/field?wt=json&analysis.fieldvalue=test+dog+cat&analysis.query=cat&analysis.showmatch=true&analysis.fieldname=item_name

How do I configure the analysis/field handler?

In solr3, I was able to perform analysis. Is this feature turned off by default in solr4?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need to add the field analysis handler to your `solrconfig.xml`:

```
<requestHandler name="/analysis/field" class="solr.FieldAnalysisRequestHandler" />
```

Comment: It's never too late to answer a question here on SO. For your answer to stand the test of time better, I've removed the reference to how old the question is, all being well your answer will age too!

Comment: and it still helped me nearly 2 years later :-D

Comment: If you are using Solr 7 and you facing the same problem. Just try on different browser. I was getting the same error on chrome, but when I went to Firefox, it was working without any modification to config.